# Mock a WP_REST_Request Object

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, url, mocking

I'm currently running some unit tests on a WordPress plug-in, using `PHPUnit` and `WP_Mock` (without connecting to WordPress database).
As the title states, I need to mock a `WP_REST_Request` Object, to give it as a parameter to a method under test.

Maybe I could do it by mocking the return of the URL used by the `WP_REST_Request::from_url()` method, or maybe with the use of `getMockFromWsdl()`.
I'm open to every kind of ideas

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ would be probably the better place for questions like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **WP_REST_Request** class implements the **ArrayAccess** interface so you can create a mock in this way:

```
$request = $this->getMockBuilder( 'ArrayAccess' )
    ->setMockClassName( 'WP_REST_Request' )
    ->getMock();
```